# Resolving conditional dependencies autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to resolve dependencies based on a condition.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Action<ContainerBuilder>> QRTypeDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, System.Action<ContainerBuilder>> () {
            { "REST" , (builder)=> builder
                                    .RegisterType<RestPublisher>()
                                    .As<Publisher>()},
            { "DB" , (builder)=> builder
                                    .RegisterType<DBPublisher>()
                                    .As<Publisher>()}
 }
```

I am just looking to make sure if this is the only way to resolve dependencies based on conditions. I have been using Ninject so far and am looking for something like the following:

```
kernel.Bind<Publisher>()
      .To<DbPublisher>()
      .When(x => Defs.AppSettings.PublisherType == "DB")
```

Just want to make sure I am doing the right thing with Autofac

Comment: Is `Defs.AppSettings.PublisherType` a configuration value that needs an application restart to change, or can it change from time to time (between requests for instance)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can see 3 solutions to achieve what you want.

1. Using a lambda

   ```
   builder.RegisterType<DbPublisher>().AsSelf();
   builder.RegisterType<RestPublisher>().AsSelf();

   builder.Register(c => { 
       switch(Defs.AppSettings.PublisherType){
           case "DB":
               c.Resolve<DbPublisher>(); 
               break; 
           case "REST":
               c.Resolve<RestPublisher>(); 
               break; 
           default:
               throw new NotSupportedException(); 
       }
   }).As<IPublisher>();
   ```
2. Using named registration

   ```
   builder.RegisterType<DbPublisher>().Named<IPublisher>("DB");
   builder.RegisterType<RestPublisher>().Named<IPublisher>("REST");

   builder.Register(c => {
         var index = c.Resolve<IIndex<String, IPublisher>>(); 
         return index[Defs.AppSettings.PublisherType]
   }.As<IPublisher>();
   ```
3. Conditional registration

   if `Defs.AppSettings.PublisherType` is defined during registration process, you can simply conditionally register your dependency :

   ```
   switch(Defs.AppSettings.PublisherType){
       case "DB":
           builder.RegisterType<DbPublisher>().As<IPublisher>();
           break; 
       case "REST":
           builder.RegisterType<RestPublisher>().As<IPublisher>(); 
           break; 
       default:
           throw new NotSupportedException(); 
   }
   ```

Comment: Here's how the docs recommend: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#selection-of-an-implementation-by-parameter-value so I'd pursue the first option

Comment: So mine was being done during the registration process. So I used the dictionary defined (to reduce the cyclometic complexity) to resolve the publisher.

Comment: #1 doesn't compile.
`c.Resolve...` needs to be `return (IPublisher)c.Resolve...`

Comment: Hey Cyril Durand, have you any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304072/how-to-resolve-dependency-in-dependency-register-time-in-autofac?noredirect=1#comment108450623_61304072