# How to resolve dependency in dependency register time in Autofac

Tags: autofac, asp.net-core-3.1

earlier I used Microsoft unity IOC. Unity container has RegisterType & Resolve method. So I able to resolve same interface with multiple implementation. but latest autofac (var builder = new ContainerBuilder();) builder hasn't resolve() method and we can't manually build (builder.Build();). 
Anyone has any idea, how to convert below code base to autofac or how to use resolve method with dependency registration.

```
container.RegisterType<IQueryManager, FirstManager>(new TypedParameter(typeof(GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType), GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType.First));
container.RegisterType<IQueryManager, SecondManager>(new TypedParameter(typeof(GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType), GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType.Two));
container.RegisterType<IQueryManager, ThirdManager>(new TypedParameter(typeof(GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType), GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType.Three));

Func<DatabaseType, IQueryManager> priceFactory = (databaseType) => container.Resolve<IQueryManager>(databaseType.ToString());
container.RegisterInstance<IQueryManagerFactory<IQueryManager>>(new QueryManagerFactory<IQueryManager>(priceFactory));
```

I try this but not working. any suggestion how to solve this with"builder.RegisterInstance".

```
builder.Register<IQueryManagerFactory<IQueryManager>>(container => new QueryManagerFactory<IQueryManager>(databaseType =>
     container.Resolve<IQueryManager>(new TypedParameter(typeof(GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType), databaseType))
));
```

Comment: maybe it's help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264172/8006943

Comment: With asp.net core 3.1 and latest autofac you can't (builder.Build();) manually and you can't register dependency after (builder.Build();)

Comment: I find your question unclear. What is it you are trying to achieve? What does Unity's "RegisterType & Resolve" do? Ca you show simple examples (class constructors and interfaces) of your code?

Comment: "RegisterType & Resolve" do same functionality as autofac, but only different is, unity allow resolve functionality during dependency registration time. But autofac not allowed to do that

Comment: Is [this what you are trying to do](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#lambda-expression-components)? I.e. registering a type with an implementation that you will resolve from the container? `container.Register<IQueryManagerFactory>(c => new QueryManagerFactory(() => c.Resolve<IQueryManager>())`

Comment: yes but I need dynamically resolve in run time base on my parameter. this is not working
builder.Register<IQueryManagerFactory<IQueryManager>>(container => new QueryManagerFactory<IQueryManager>(databaseType =>
                container.Resolve<IQueryManager>(new TypedParameter(typeof(GeneralEnumerations.DatabaseType), databaseType))
            ));